# Creating svelte components within their definition with snake case

Tags: svelte, svelte-component

I'm examining the following source code written in Svelte to be more capable at this framework:
https://github.com/revolist/svelte-datagrid

One repeating pattern encountered across the project confuses me completely:

Each component under the `src/svelte` directory initiates itself with the snake case notation that is consistent with its file name. For example, the `RevogrViewportScroll.svelte` component initiates itself as seen below:

```
<revogr-viewport-scroll 
  content-width={contentWidth}
  content-height={contentHeight}
  on:scrollViewport={onEvent}
  on:resizeViewport={onEvent}
  on:scrollchange={onEvent}
  bind:this={__ref}
>
  <slot></slot>
</revogr-viewport-scroll>
```

I didn't understand what is the point of such a use and how it achieves to initiate itself through this use.

Answer (score 0):

In general it doesn't do anything special `<revogr-viewport-scroll>` is equivalent to `<div>` in HTML5

That said, this *specific* library is simply a wrapper around [RevoGrid](https://github.com/revolist/revogrid)
which is a library that offers web components allowing you to use those elements as described here: [basic usage](https://github.com/revolist/revogrid/blob/master/docs/indexhtml.md)

Comment: I don't think so. Each component is populated in props defined in the respective components.

Comment: you are right, I misunderstood the question, I have amended the answer :)

Comment: You don't answer the point I emphasize.

Comment: It's not "creating svelte components" is what I meant, the `<revogr-viewport-scroll>` is **not** a svelte component